# Back-propagation with complex parameters in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

Currently I'm trying to train a complex data generated from telecom engineering models. The weights and biases are also complex. I have used the relu activation for the hidden layers as follows at the l-th layer:

```
A_l = tf.complex(tf.nn.relu(tf.real(Z_l)), tf.nn.relu(tf.imag(Z_l)))
```

But how to do it for the cost and optimizer, please? I am really confused because I'm a beginner in machine learning. I have gone through some papers about non-analytic functions, but none of them helped to use the Tensorflow API. For example: how do I rewrite the functions below?

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = Z_out, labels = y)) 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

I have seen a recommendation to split the cost as real and imaginary parts as:

```
cost_R = .., cost_I = ...
```

but I didn't try it because I think the optimizer will be split and the optimization not be working. I used the relu activation for the hidden layers as follows at the l-th layer:

```
A_l = tf.complex(tf.nn.relu(tf.real(Z_l)), tf.nn.relu(tf.imag(Z_l)))
```

But how to the cost and optimizer? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How about this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015467/minimizing-a-function-of-a-complex-variable

Comment: This helps to define the cost function in the complex domain. But, the problem is Back-propagation. It has to compute derivatives wrt complex weights and biases which are complex. So i am looking for a way to do it in Tensorflow as mensioned above. Thank you for your concern.